# LINQ OrderBy() fails on List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a very simple code like this. After the execution, the list rArray remains unchanged. It is supposed to be sorted based on Level, but it is not. Any ideas? Please help. Thanks. This is in Microsoft C# WPF.

```
    private class RecordList
    {
        public string NodeID { get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
        public RecordList(string theID, int theLevel)
        {
            this.NodeID = theID;
            this.Level = theLevel;
        }
    }

    private void Test()
    {
        List<RecordList> rArray = new List<RecordList>();
        rArray.Add(new RecordList("Consolidated", 0));
        rArray.Add(new RecordList("Large Volume", 2));
        rArray.Add(new RecordList("Small Volume", 2));
        rArray.Add(new RecordList("Detailed Record 1", 4));
        rArray.Add(new RecordList("Detailed Record 2", 4));
        rArray.Add(new RecordList("Midium Volume", 2));
        rArray.OrderBy(RecordList => RecordList.Level);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

this

`rArray.OrderBy(RecordList => RecordList.Level)`

will NOT change your array. It will create new IEnumerable collection. 
If you want to save it to array, you will have to do smtg like

`rArray = rArray.OrderBy(RecordList => RecordList.Level).ToList()`

Answer (score -1):

I resolved it by doing the following. That is, OrderBy method returns something instead of directly alter the source.

```
        IOrderedEnumerable<RecordList> aList = rArray.OrderBy(RecordList => RecordList.Level);
        rArray = aList.ToList<RecordList>();
```

Comment: Thanks for tym32167's answer. I posted my own resolution before seeing your reply. It's similar.

Comment: It seems like this is the same answer from above..kindly recognize @tym32167 answer.

Comment: Plus it seems he posted the answer first, it would be nice if you could accept his answer.